# PHP basic form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm building a website that is password-protected but I can't seem get it to work properly. I have it set to go to the homepage if the password is correct & to a different page if the password is incorrect. I have written the code but every time I run it, it goes right to the page that displays if the password is wrong. I know something is missing from the code but I'm not sure what it is.

HTML

```
<table>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Permission" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

PHP

```
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if ($pass == "Password") {
header('Location:home.php');
} else {
header('Location:wrong.php');
exit;
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Sidenote: `header('Location:home.php'); exit;`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. `Password` and `password` are not the same thing, should that be the case. See my above comment about adding `exit;` to your first header. Plus, hash your passwords, you WILL get hacked by using plain text passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking to see if the form is submitted. You're just going straight into your logic.

And easy way to check to see if the page has received a form submission is to check the request method.

```
if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if ($pass == "Password") {
    header('Location:home.php');
    } else {
    header('Location:wrong.php');
    exit;
    }
}
```

You can also check to see if `$_POST['submit']` is set and has a value.

FYI, might want to put an `exit` after the first call to `header()`. Also, this isn't a great way to go about checking passwords. Might want to consider using a database and hashed passwords. You should also add some data validation (i.e. make sure the password field isn't blank).

Comment: what you are doing...comparing `$pass` with `Password`

Comment: I tested OP's code, I am unable to reproduce, but my test was successful while using simple echos (right/wrong).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $_POST['password'] AND $_POST['password'] == "Password") 
{
    header('Location:home.php');
} else 
{
    header('Location:wrong.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this around your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

}
```

It'll work fine then, upon page load the code is being read, and as $_POST['password'] has no value at this stage you're being redirected to wrong.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if ($pass == "Password") {
    header('Location:home.php');
    } else {
    header('Location:wrong.php');
    exit;
    }
}
else{
    echo'<table>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <tr>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Permission" /></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following system with the following pages:

index.php - here we will have our login form

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if ((isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] == "Password") || $_SESSION['auth'] == 1)
    {
        header('Location:home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location:wrong.php');
    }
?>

<table>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Permission" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Your home.php file

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_GET['logout'] == 1)
    {
        session_destroy();
    }

    if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 1)
    {
        //show stuff to the logged in user
        //display log-out option
        echo '<a href="home.php?logout=1">Logout</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        //redirect the user to the login page
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
?>
```